# Performance : SQL Queries vs Server-Side PHP Loops (MYSQL vs PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, loops

I have not seen much info on this topic and require some data . I am new to using complex MySQL queries and i was wondering about the performance costs of Complex queries in comparison to a simple query and then run server side php calculations on it .

E.g :

'Simple' query :

```
SELECT id as ID, date(x_date),  v_price as price
                From tableX
                WHERE v_price IN 
                (
                    select MIN(v_price) from tableX
                    GROUP BY week(x_date)
                )
            )
```

Now lets say i want to count the number of times similar prices occurred .

I can do it in 2 ways .

A) Use a foreach loop server side php and calculate the data

B) Do another select in sql

```
group by price
ORDER BY COUNT(price) DESC
```

Which is the best way to proceed ? via SQL or server code (php)

What are the performance costs , time , server load etc.....

Comment: sql, written efficiently, will almost always be faster

Answer (score 3):

First, doing the work in the database is almost always better.  This is discussed many times for each context where someone wants to do RBAR (row-by-agonizing row) processing.

Second, it is highly unlikely that this "simple" query does what you want:

```
SELECT id as ID, date(x_date), v_price as price
From tableX
WHERE v_price IN (select MIN(v_price) from tableX FROM tableX GROUP BY week(x_date))
```

This returns all rows in `tableX` where the minimum price matches *any* week's minimum price.  More likely, you want:

```
SELECT id as ID, date(x_date), v_price as price
From tableX
WHERE (yearweek(x_date), v_price) IN (
          select yearweek(x_date), MIN(v_price)
          from tableX 
          group by yearweek(x_date)
         );
```

Note that this also takes the year into account.

Answer (score 1):

Let' consider following example

```
select MIN(v_price) from tableX
```

What this will do is it will look up tableX by an index and find lowest price.
Now let's try to do it outside of DB server. First you have to get data from DB

```
select v_price from tableX
```

I hope you are seeing the difference already. It means pulling lot of data from storage on DB side and lot of data transfer. Even if your application and DB will be on the same machine it will mean lot of memory consumed and lot of CPU cycles spent on it.
So simple answer is do it in DB as it is almost always faster and less resource intensive.